# How do we can duplicate the files using Batch File where name of the generated file can be controlled?

Tags: batch-file, automation

I have written below `bat` file, which duplicates the file from `source` folder to `destination`

```
 for /l %%A in (1,1,5) do copy "C:\source\Device-DAY0-Sample0.dat" "C:\dest\Device-DAY%%A-Sample%%A.dat"
```

This generates files as follow :

- Device-DAY1-Sample1.dat
- Device-DAY2-Sample2.dat
- Device-DAY3-Sample3.dat
- Device-DAY4-Sample4.dat
- Device-DAY5-Sample5.dat

But, I am trying to generate 3 samples per day as shown below :

- Device-DAY1-Sample1.dat
- Device-DAY1-Sample2.dat
- Device-DAY1-Sample3.dat
- Device-DAY2-Sample1.dat
- Device-DAY2-Sample2.dat
- Device-DAY2-Sample3.dat

How can I improve my code?

Comment: You could also use Autoit. Maybe the code is more intuitive to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
for /l %%B in (1,1,10) do (
for /l %%A in (1,1,3) do (
Copy "C:\source\Device-DAY0-Sample0.dat" "C:\dest\Device-DAY%%B-Sample%%A.dat"
)
)
pause>nul
```